# How to use value from select in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am trying to join a select statement. But the subquery select returns WAY too many rows, making it extremely slow - because I can't get the ID from the first select into the subquery.

The error is:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ritzau_data.News.id' in 'where clause'

How do I get this id in the first select into the select inside the join?
I made something similar in MSSQL - that works fine. I will paste the working MSSQL code as well.

MySQLCode (not working):

```
select News.id as newsid, header as title, content as contents, created as published_time, 2883 as drupalid, isins, categories, NewsTypes.npName from ritzau_data.News,
(
    select idNews, group_concat(isin separator ', ') as isins
    from ritzau_data.NewsIsin
    where idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
    group by idNews

) as isins,
(
    select idNews, group_concat(distinct Category separator ', ') as categories
    from ritzau_data.NewsTags

    inner join ritzau_data.TagsCategoriesMap on NewsTags.idTag = TagsCategoriesMap.idTags
    inner join ritzau_data.Categories on TagsCategoriesMap.idCategories = Categories.id
    where idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
    group by idNews
) as categories

left join ritzau_data.NewsTypes on News.idType = NewsTypes.id
inner join ritzau_data.NewsReceivers on News.id = NewsReceivers.idNews
where ritzau_data.News.id > 100 and idReceiver = 3
order by News.id
limit 100;
```

MSSQLCode (working):

```
SELECT TOP 1000 news.id AS newsid, 
        cast(title as varchar(256)) AS title, cast(contents as text)AS contents, published_time, users.drupalid,
        cast (STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + isin
                FROM news_instruments t1
                left join instruments t2 on t1.instrument_id = t2.id
                where news_id = news.id
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''
        ) as text) AS isins,
        cast(STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',' + t2.name
                FROM news_categories t1
                left join categories t2 on t1.category_id = t2.id
                where news_id = news.id
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''
        ) as text) AS categories
        from news
        left join users on news.locked_userid = users.id
        where news.id > @offsetid
```

The first query - it works but is extremely slow

```
select News.id as newsid, header as title, content as contents, created as published_time, 2883 as drupalid, isins, categories, NewsTypes.npName from ritzau_data.News    
left join ritzau_data.NewsTypes on News.idType = NewsTypes.id
inner join ritzau_data.NewsReceivers on News.id = NewsReceivers.idNews
select idNews, group_concat(isin separator ', ') as isins
        from ritzau_data.NewsIsin
        where idNews = News.id
        group by idNews
) as isins on News.id = isins.idNews
left join (
        select idNews, group_concat(distinct Category separator ', ') as categories
        from ritzau_data.NewsTags

        inner join ritzau_data.TagsCategoriesMap on NewsTags.idTag = TagsCategoriesMap.idTags
        inner join ritzau_data.Categories on TagsCategoriesMap.idCategories = Categories.id
        where idNews = News.id
        group by idNews
) as categories on News.id = categories.idNews
where News.id > @idoffset and idReceiver = 3
order by News.id
limit 100;
```

Comment: I made this 2 procedures - one to extract id's and one to extract data. Now it is much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the news table is in a differen schema, therefore you would have to provide the fully qualified name in the where clause:

```
select [...]
from ritzau_data.News
[...]
where ritzau_data.News.id > @idoffset and idReceiver = 3
order by News.id
limit 100;
```

The elegant way is to give tables aliases:

```
select [...]
from ritzau_data.News nw
[...]
where nw.id > @idoffset and idReceiver = 3
order by nw.id
limit 100;
```

**Update:**
YOu have to pull the join in the subqueries to the News table out of the subqueries:

```
SELECT News.id AS newsid, header AS title, content AS contents, created AS published_time, 2883 AS drupalid, isins, categories, NewsTypes.npName 
FROM ritzau_data.News ritzau_data.News
JOIN
(
    SELECT idNews, GROUP_CONCAT(isin SEPARATOR ', ') AS isins
    FROM ritzau_data.NewsIsin
    GROUP BY idNews

) AS isins
  ON isins.idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
 JOIN
(
    SELECT idNews, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories
    FROM ritzau_data.NewsTags

    INNER JOIN ritzau_data.TagsCategoriesMap ON NewsTags.idTag = TagsCategoriesMap.idTags
    INNER JOIN ritzau_data.Categories ON TagsCategoriesMap.idCategories = Categories.id
    GROUP BY idNews
) AS categories
  ON categories.idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
LEFT JOIN ritzau_data.NewsTypes ON News.idType = NewsTypes.id
INNER JOIN ritzau_data.NewsReceivers ON News.id = NewsReceivers.idNews
WHERE ritzau_data.News.id > 100 AND idReceiver = 3
ORDER BY News.id
LIMIT 100;
```

**Update2:**
pulling the join to News into the subqueries:

```
SELECT News.id AS newsid, header AS title, content AS contents, created AS published_time, 2883 AS drupalid, isins, categories, NewsTypes.npName 
FROM ritzau_data.News ritzau_data.News
JOIN
(
    SELECT idNews, GROUP_CONCAT(isin SEPARATOR ', ') AS isins
    FROM ritzau_data.NewsIsin
    JOIN ritzau_data.News ON idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
    GROUP BY idNews

) AS isins
 JOIN
(
    SELECT idNews, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories
    FROM ritzau_data.NewsTags

    INNER JOIN ritzau_data.TagsCategoriesMap ON NewsTags.idTag = TagsCategoriesMap.idTags
    INNER JOIN ritzau_data.Categories ON TagsCategoriesMap.idCategories = Categories.id
    JOIN ritzau_data.News ON idNews = ritzau_data.News.id
    GROUP BY idNews
) AS categories
LEFT JOIN ritzau_data.NewsTypes ON News.idType = NewsTypes.id
INNER JOIN ritzau_data.NewsReceivers ON News.id = NewsReceivers.idNews
WHERE ritzau_data.News.id > 100 AND idReceiver = 3
ORDER BY News.id
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Adding the full name does nothing. I have updated the question with new code.

Comment: I see the problem now, you are using the `News.id` in the categories subselect. That does not work, you have to select all rows from categories and then join that subquery with the News table, or you have to add the news table in the subquery. I will update my answer.

Comment: That does work - it looks alot like the first query i made (see updated question), but it takes 122 seconds to run the query, because the joins returns too many rows.  The joins should only get results that has the News.is selected in the beginning.

Comment: you can always add the News table into the subqueries. If the indexes are set correctly, that might be faster, see updated solution.

Comment: Hmm not faster. I still think that is is joining way too much data.

Comment: run an explain plan and see what indexes it uses.